# C function to swap two chars in a char[] segfaults, despite not working with string literals

Tags: c, string, swap

I've verified in GDB that the program crashes on the *(a) = *(b) line. This does not make sense to me.

In my main function I allocated a 5 bytes for the char* string. I pass two pointers to swap, one is string offset by sizeof(char) and the other is the pointer to string. These pointers are copied to swap()'s call stack. The 5 bytes I allocated earlier should still be on the stack so swap() should have no problem with dereferencing and writing to those locations on stack, right?

```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      char *string = "abcd";
      swap((string+1), string);
      printf("%s\n",string);
      return 0;
  }

  void swap(char *a, char *b)                                                                                                                                                                       
  {
       if(!a || !b)
           return;

       char temp = *(a);
       *(a) = *(b);
       *(b) = temp;
   }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but `*(a)` is over-parenthesized, `*a` is enough.

Comment: I'm puzzled. Where did you think you were allocating five bytes for the string, and how is this not a usage of string literals?

Comment: @elchonon-edelson I think the original poster has an incorrect understanding of what `char*` is, as a string whose bytes are copied to the stack instead of just a `char` pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *string = "abcd";
```

is a pointer to a string literal and string literals are immutable in C. Modifying a string literal invokes undefined behavior.

Change the declaration of `string` to:

```
char string[] = "abcd";
```

to fix you program. Here `string` is an array, initialized with the content of a string literal and is modifiable.

Comment: crazy enough, but I had no idea this was the case in C, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

String literals like `"abcd"` are read only, you must not change them. Use

```
char string[] = "abcd";
```

instead.

Comment: You can initialize a `char[]` with a regular string literal and it'll still be writable.  You don't have to write out the `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }`.  (Unless you *really* don't want the terminating NUL, which does occasionally come up.)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `char string[] = "abcd";`, becase string is  inmuttable in `char* string= "abcd";`